# Clear the previous copy of same screen from Navigation Backstack in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have two screens, Screen A and Screen B. Screen A can take user to Screen B and Screen B can take user to Screen A. The problem is that I cannot use the previous copy of Screen A when I go to Screen A from Screen B. I want to finish the app when it's on Screen A and user presses back button.

I tried using

`popUpTo(ScreenA){ inclusive = true }`

but it still takes me to Screen A from Screen A when I press back.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like there are multiple Screen As. Try this: while navigating, use `launchSingleTop = true` as a navigation argument right where you have `inclusive = true`. Do that wherever you are navigating. More info: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/navigation/NavOptionsBuilder#launchSingleTop()